# How can I configure a my switch to allow multiple VLANs on 1 port?

Tags: networking, switch, vlan, dell

I am not sure if my title describes this well or not.

Basically I have a Dell PowerConnect 2824 web managed switch. Currently the switch is running with ports 1 through 12 in VLAN 10. This is going to be for the computers in the office. What I am looking to do is allow VLAN 20 to also use the same ports but have that VLAN ID for the phones only.

Where I seem to be running into a snag is everything I read about these switches tells me I have to first assign the VLAN membership for each port. Then I have to go into the port settings and assign a PVID to each port so the traffic will be tagged with that VLAN in this case 10.

Here is what VLAN 10 membership looks like;

[image: VLAN 10]

Here is what each of the ports looks like;

[image: VLAN 10 PORT 2]

According to what I read I have to assign a PVID, I know at least when messing with VMware that a VLAN ID of 4095 is "All VLAN IDs". Is the same true here too?

Any ideas?

Comment: So, am I right if I say that... 1) for every VoIP phone that are directly connected to your 2824, you want to configure the related port as a TRUNK with VLAN 20 (tagged) and VLAN 10 (untagged / PVID); and 2) you're deploying VoIP phone that have an embedded switch; and 3) your VoIP phone will be configured so to act (VoIP calls/registration) on VLAN 20 and forward untagged traffic (VLAN 10) to the downlink/PC.... Am I wrong?

Comment: Also, please confirm you've got a look to the [official user guide](http://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_networking/esuprt_net_fxd_prt_swtchs/powerconnect-2824_user's%20guide_en-us.pdf), with particular reference to page 124 (Configuring VLANs) and  page 128 (Defining VLAN Ports Settings).

Comment: I found this caption in the user guide. That explained exactly what I needed. "The VLAN Port Settings page contains fields for managing ports that are part of a VLAN. The port
default VLAN ID (PVID) is configured on the VLAN Port Settings page. All untagged packets arriving to
the device are tagged by the ports PVID.
To open the VLAN Port Settings page, click Switch-->VLAN-->Port Settings in the tree view" So I already set a VLAN tag then it will not override my tag.

Comment: What about my first comment?

Comment: Oh sorry, yes what I trying to do is what you describe in #2. I want the phones connected to the 2824 and the computers connected to the phones via the internal switch.

Comment: Ok. But are you able to configure your VoIP phones so that they will handle the TAGged packets (on VLAN 20)? This is a key point, as without a proper configuration of your VoIP phones, it's basically useless to configure a trunk on your switch ports.

Comment: From what I was able to find via a quick search it looks like the phones will  support VLAN tagging. I need to find some official documentation to verify this.